# ECMAScriptの新バージョンの機能を利用できるようになるライブラリの総称

Tags: javascript

現在、IE11をサポート対象としたWebアプリケーションを作っています。
ここで、IE11ではサポートされていないECMAScript6で追加された関数などを使いたいと考えています。
新たに追加された構文はさすがに無理だとしても、例えばString.prototypeに追加されたメソッドなどは、簡単に同等のものを自作できるので、そのようなライブラリがすでにあるだろうと踏んでいます。
ただ、検索キーワードが分からないので、探せなくて困っている状況です。

このようなライブラリを総称する用語はあるでしょうか？
AltJSとかトランスパイラとか、そういった類の用語です（が、ほしいのはトランスパイラではなく、手軽に導入できる、ただのライブラリです）。

Comment: ご参考です。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33650/。babelというトランスパイラがあります。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

一般的にAPIインターフェイスをすこし変更するための簡単なラッパーのことを`shim`と称し、特にWebブラウザーでサポートされていない機能を追加するためのライブラリーを`polyfill`と呼びます。

Answer (score 0):

よく使われる用語では無さそうな気がしますが、検索ワードとして "ECMAScript 6 compatible library" を使ってググると https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim がヒットしました。